# What is the sentence structure in PPT bullet points?

Tags: sentence-structure, sentence

My teacher told me that, when writing slides for ppt presentation, I am not supposed to use a complete sentence structure like: "In this chapter the author also outlines the organization of the book."

I am supposed to use a sentence structure like

> - Outline the organization of the book

My question is, what is the name for this kind of sentence structure?

Comment: It's the title of that section of the presentation, similar to chapter titles in a book.

Comment: It has the grammatical structure of an imperative, though it’s unlikely that as a PowerPoint bullet, its intended function is to command the audience.

Comment: The example you've given *(Outline the organization of the book)* is an ***imperative*** sentence. That's ***not*** normally used "when writing slides for ppt presentation" - it's typical of how your *teacher* might present the assignment to you (***you*** being the implied subject of the imperative construction; she's giving *you* instruction on what you're supposed to do). In such a context, the text at each bullet point effectively means *At this stage in the process, **this** is what you must do*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok so what will be a ppt bullet point sentence look like?

Comment: ppt bullet point headings are normally ***noun phrases*** that identify the subject matter of that part of the presentation. Normal sentence syntax is irrelevant, so you wouldn't normally include unnecessary determiners or words which are contextually obvious. For your specific case, the bullet point would probably just be ***Outline*** (a *noun*, not the *verb* that your teacher might use when telling you what to do). This is nothing to do with "grammar", and it makes no sense to refer to the text of a bullet point as a "sentence".

Comment: This is also not intrinsically about the English language. VTC.

Comment: A bulleted list is a shopping list and can take on any form: Apples, Bananas, Check motor oil prices, She'll kill me if I forget the birthday candles. In school or work, you'd be consistent: Outline book, Give examples, Thank audience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a "fragment". That is, it is potentially part of sentence, the missing parts are understood from context.  In this case, I assume that the context allows the reader to "fill in" the subject "(The author will) outline...."

Another common type of fragment is a noun phrase.

- A fragment
- Not a sentence that contains an independent clause

I these cases, you would understand each bullet point to say "(This is) a fragment" and "(It is) not a sentence..."

Now in your example, the fragment could be analysed as an imperative sentence, meaning "(You must) outline...."  Only context can distinguish the imperative from the fragment.